# Index Seek takes looong time on large table

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I have the following Indexes created for the two tables which created by our BI team:

```
    CREATE INDEX idx_Used_Q2_2021_package_table_IDX1
    ON Used_Q2_2021_package_table (OrganizationId, OrganizationItemId,OrganizationPackageId);

    CREATE INDEX idx_SupTransaction_detail_one_org_Q2_2021_package_table_IDX1
    ON SupTransaction_detail_one_org_Q2_2021_package_table (OrganizationId,  OrganizationItemId,OrganizationPackageId);

    CREATE INDEX idx_SupTransaction_detail_one_org_Q2_2021_package_table_IDX2
    ON SupTransaction_detail_one_org_Q2_2021_package_table (OrganizationId);
```

All of the columns are type GUID, the table has no primary key columns.  The first table has around 5.3 million rows and the second table has 30 million rows.

I ran the following query and it takes very long

```
        SELECT  L.OrganizationId, L.OrganizationItemId, L.OrganizationPackageId
    FROM  [SpaceTraxBI].dbo.Used_Q2_2021_package_table  as L 
    LEFT JOIN [SpaceTraxBI].dbo.SupTransaction_detail_one_org_Q2_2021_package_table  as R
    ON R.OrganizationId = L.OrganizationId
        AND R.OrganizationItemId = L.OrganizationItemId
        AND R.OrganizationPackageId = L.OrganizationPackageId
        WHERE R.OrganizationId ='c0e0dc89-1bcc-4cc2-b71d-5d14d93c9a32'
```

When I look at the live Query statistic I see the Index Seeks on the 2nd table (one with 30 million rows) is the slow point when it attempt to read 137,000 rows, the same index seek on the first table  for 15,000 rows occurs almost instantly.

The amount of time it takes to seek 20k row in the 2nd table is around 20 seconds whereas it takes .009 seconds to seek similar amount of data in the first table.

[image]

Any advice on what I should attempt to do to improve this? I already setup 4 separate files on my tempDB data files and they sit on SSD.  I allocated 90% of the server RAM for SQL server.

These two tables are purely for read operation with no other update/delete operations on them nor I'm aware of other connection doing read the same time as I do.

Is this a fundamental issue where the table is just too big for any type of query to be efficient?

**Update 1:**

Estimate Execution Plan: With Index Seek has 137,000 rows as estimate number of rows.

[image]

**Update 2:**

At 95% completion I can see the query plan shows the Hash Match result has 490 million rows return as oppose to the estimated 7732 rows.

[image]

**Update 3:**

Due to the memory overflow, I tried to modify my query to do a count() instead and I see this query returns around 500 million rows and the execution plan is similar to the estimated one... so this is back to my original point is I wonder this is a fundamental issue where there is just too much data involved in a query and no amount of tweaking I do will help...the next step is to ask the BI developer to rewrite their table/query?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add an actual [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) too?

Comment: I'll try and see if I can obtain it, I let the query ran and it stops at 99% index seek which took around 7 minutes before the error message appear: An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.  I think this mean the result return too many rows...

Comment: @Fylix Do try to get the **actual** execution plan, but in the meantime you should be able to get at least the **estimated** execution plan, almost immediately. That may give a hint at if you're experiencing a cardinality estimate issue of sorts if the estimated execution plan thinks it's going to return a lot more rows from your tables than what realistically makes sense.

Comment: Your index seeks are unlikely to be taking much time at all, your hash join is though. Are you really expecting this many results? Joining 15K rows to 130K rows to get 490 million rows is about 25% of the way to a cross join. Returning that many rows into SSMS to display at once is never going to work - a real application would just fetch a handful of rows at a time (as the user needs to read them).

Comment: 60 or so bytes per row * 500m is about 30Gb so it is a lot of data to be shifting around. Can you share an **actual** execution plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan